# Sorting in ExtJS column removes node from template column

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs, extjs4

I have a template column in a grid which I am rendering a sparkline graph to: http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline and when I sort the grid the canvas element that is rendered by the plugin is destroyed. Is there a way to stop the contents of a row being altered during a sort? I'm using ExtJS 4.2.3

Libraries:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="//omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/2.1.2/jquery.sparkline.min.js"></script>
```

Code:

```
Ext.application({
    name : 'Fiddle',

    launch : function() {
        Ext.create("Ext.grid.Panel", {
            store: new Ext.data.Store({
                data: [
                    {
                        thing: '1'
                    },
                    {
                        thing: '1'
                    },
                    {
                        thing: '1'
                    },
                    {
                        thing: '1'
                    },
                    {
                        thing: '1'
                    }
                ],
                fields: [
                    "thing"
                ]
            }),
            columns: [
                {
                    text: 'Hello',
                    xtype: 'templatecolumn',
                    tpl: Ext.create('Ext.XTemplate', "<div id='1'></div>"),
                    flex: 1
                },
                {
                    text: 'Other',
                    flex: 1,
                    dataIndex: 'thing'
                }
            ],
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            listeners: {
                boxready: function() {
                    $('#1').sparkline([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
                }
            }
        });

    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[sortchange](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.grid.Panel-event-sortchange)

```
listeners: {
            boxready: function() {
                $('#1').sparkline([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10])
            },
            sortChange: function() {
                // your logic here
            }
        }
```

Comment: So I would need to re render the sparkline on every sort?

Comment: The grid rows are changed on sort - So, I suppose you'll have to.